# Making Div tag resize according to browser size when using jquery.flashgallery to display the image gallery

Tags: php, jquery, swfobject

```
<div id="banner">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/flashgallery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/gallery.swf', 'gallery/config.xml',{ width:'100%',    height:'100%', allowFullScreen: 'true', background: 'transparent'});
</script>



</div>
```

Here i want to make banner div to resize when i resize the browser window
can some body help on this Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

My last post was by accident, try something like this. I have not tried it though.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var divRatio = .7;
    var divHeight = $(window).height()) * divRatio;
    var divWidth = $(window).width()) * divRatio;
    $('.yourDivYouWantHere').css({
        height : divHeight;
        width : divWidth;
    });
}
```

Kevin

Comment: oops you may want to put more thought into the divRatio aspect, but you get the idea.